# Laravel Nova how to fix the /nova route not working

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-6, laravel-nova

I have an `laravel`-application which has the `laravel-nova`-adminpanel attached to it. Previously, when I went to the route `myapplication.test/nova` - I get prompted to the nova login page.
Now, on the `web.php`-file, I added a route like this:

```
Route::get('{sitemap}', 'SitemapController@show')->name('sitemap.show');
```

the `myapplication.test/nova`-route is no longer working and I have no clue why?

Inside the `nova.php`-file I added `'path' => '/nova/admin',` - then it works, but is there are way to avoid this?

Comment: `{sitemap}` it catch all the route so don't add this in top add in end of `web.php`

Comment: @KamleshPaul yeah, tried that but it did not work :/

Comment: so if you remove this then it works?

Answer (score 0):

**First:**

```
Route::get('{sitemap}', 'SitemapController@show')->name('sitemap.show');
```

This mails all urls like '/test', '/nova', 'test.html' must go to the SitemapController show method.

I don't think you want this, so I think you need to change is to:

```
Route::get('sitemap', 'SitemapController@show')->name('sitemap.show');
```

**Second:**
Route are normally cached. So to see the change working be sure to run:

```
php artisan route:cache
```

Or use a commend to clear all cache

```
php artisan optimize:clear
```